# Ubuntu 18.04 integrated graphics display glitch

Tags: graphics, xorg, integrated

I'm setting up a Dell Inspiron dual-boot to Ubuntu 18.04.  On the Ubuntu side, I've switched the graphics card used for the display to the integrated card: Settings -> About shows Graphics as "Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)".*

However, this causes two green glitch bars on the desktop after each reboot, as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9B9F.jpg, as well as display failures in certain applications such as Skype and emacs.  Curiously, Firefox seems fine.  The glitches generally get worse after waking the machine from sleep.

I ran a GPU memory test on the Windows side and found no issues.

Any ideas for how to fix this (not using the discrete graphics card)?  Or what the source of the problem might be?

---

*: For what it is worth, I got Ubuntu to claim it is using the integrated card (while still having the touchscreen work) by copying the contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and creating the following `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Driver          "intel"
    BusId           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "intel"
    Device          "intel"
EndSection
```

I had read others claim to be able to use the "PRIME Profiles" tab of the nvidia-settings tool for this purpose, but mine had no such tab.

More integrated card info:

```
> sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0896
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 162
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried Wayland?

Log-off and change the desktop to 'Ubuntu (Wayland)' or something like that.

I had a few bugs that were similar to what you are experiencing with screen tearing as well, and changing it to Wayland fixed it for me.

Maybe it was something else I changed, but after I switched to Wayland, it got fixed.

Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: I had to first enable selection by commenting out `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.  This seems to work, though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I generated a custom xorg.conf (Ctrl-Alt-F6 to get to a terminal, `killall Xorg`, `sudo Xorg -configure`, `sudo mv /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, reboot to get X back with new .conf) and after noticing glitching I looked in the xorg.conf and it had picked up the deprecated `xserver-xorg-video-intel` "intel" driver instead of the built-in "modesetting" driver from the kernel. I had to remove that package and regenerate (or just change "intel" to "modesetting" in the xorg.conf)